# как развернуть готовый проект на vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, консоль

Скинули информацию с сервера, где готовый проект на "Vue"

- Установил глобально vue/cli
- vue create .
- npm run build
  У меня поверх моего проекта создался дефолтный вариант
  Вопрос один, реально ли развернуть это вообще ?

Comment: `vue create .` - этим ты создал новый проект в тек. директории, его и получил.

Comment: у меня в скачанном с сервера файле имеется такая структура:
-css
-fonts
-js
  -app.bf90.js
  -appbf90.js.map
  -chunk-vendors
index.html
package-lock.json

Comment: Очень рад за структуру. В данном случае создания нового проекта "поверх", она не имеет никакого значения. Если хочешь работать с уже имеющимся проектом - просто не заменяй его новым (вызывать `vue create` тогда не надо).

Comment: в файле index.html у меня ссылки на чанки.
в сухом остатке, возможно ли как-то открыть этот проект, я слышал через babel 
как я понимаю он был скомпилирован через webpack

Comment: Паша, не понятен вопрос. У вас просто есть html'ка и js/css бандлы собранные вебпаком которые сделал кто-то до вас? Что вы хотите? Как-то запустить сайтик? Ну положите это в папочку на который ведет домен. Хотите сделать VUE проект и что-то там исправить? Ну никак, ищите человека который делал это и просите у него доступ в репозиторий. Фарш невозможно прокрутить назад (насколько я знаю) - vue проект из бандлов вы не получите.

Comment: @Александр, "никак" в случае Vue не совсем верно: для изменения - безусловно, потребуются исходники... но когда на странице предполагается несколько независимых вебприложений построенных с этой библиотекой (несколько vue-инстансов), разработка каждого из них не требует исходников остальных - достаточно правильно собрать общий вендор чанк. Хотя конечно не факт что в данном случае имеем дело со вторым вариантом :)

Comment: Почитайте как поднять проект на vue (если сам проект то на vue написан)

Comment: всем спасибо! 
обратился к разработчику, он дал мне ссылку на репозиторий...
ругался я долго